# Finding shortest path with genetic algorithm

Tags: java, tree, network-programming, genetic-algorithm, shortest-path

I am trying to develop java program for finding the shortest path with genetic algorithm in weighted graph. I am having difficulties in coding based on this algorithm. Can someone show me sample codes for this problem. Any language is okay. Any information like libraries or others that might be helpful for this problem is also okay. Most important thing right now is to test the time to find the shortest path based on this algorithm and I need to find out before due date for my assignment. So if anyone can help me,please.

I was coding based on java and I have difficulties mostly in cross over and mutation process. And also defining fitness function is also a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Java example of a shortest path genetic algorithm

```
package ga;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GA {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //computation time
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        //population size
        int populationSize = 30;
        //Number of Cities
        int numCities = 15;
        //Mutation rate
        double mutationRate = 0.05;
        //Crossover Rate
        double crossoverRate = 0.8;
        //Choose File path or if false randomly created Path
        boolean useFile = false;
        //Name the file to be used
        String fileName = "Data.txt";
        //Current Number of Generations
        int numberOfGenerations = 0;
        //Stop Condition
        int stopAt=2500;
        //Population
        Population pop;
        //use GA or Brute Force
        boolean GAuse=true;



        //Selecting File mode or Random Mode
        if (useFile == false) {

            pop = new Population(populationSize, numCities, crossoverRate, mutationRate);

        } else {
            FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);
            numCities=file.getNumCities();
            crossoverRate=file.getCrossoverRate();
            mutationRate=file.getMutationRate();
            populationSize=file.getCities().length;
            Path p = new Path(file.getNumCities());
            p.setPath(file.getCities());
            pop = new Population(populationSize, numCities, p,crossoverRate ,mutationRate );

        }
        if(GAuse==true){

      //Sorting the population from Finess / Evaluating
        pop.FitnessOrder();

                //Prints each path ID/Cost/Fitness/City order(with coordinates)
         for (int i = 0; i < pop.getPopulation().length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Path ID: "+i+" | Cost: "+pop.getPopulation()[i].getCost()+" | Fitness: "+pop.getPopulation()[i].getFitness()+"%");
            System.out.print("Path is: ");
            for (int j = 0; j < pop.getPopulation()[i].getPath().length; j++) {
                System.out.print(pop.getPopulation()[i].getPath()[j].getId() +"("+pop.getPopulation()[i].getPath()[j].getX()+","+pop.getPopulation()[i].getPath()[j].getY()+")  ");

         }System.out.println("\n -----------------------------------------------------");
        }

      //Start looking for possible solution
        while (numberOfGenerations !=stopAt) {

            //Select / Crossover
            while (pop.Mate() == false);              
            //Mutate
            for (int i = 0; i < pop.getNextGen().length; i++) {
            pop.getNextGen()[i].setPath(pop.Mutation(pop.getNextGen()[i].getPath()));

            }

            //Setting the new Generation to current Generation
            pop.setPopulation(pop.getNextGen());
            pop.setDone(0);
            //Sorting the new population from Finess / Evaluating
            pop.FitnessOrder();
            //Incremente number of Generations
            numberOfGenerations++;
        }


      //Prints out the fitness of each path
        double valor=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < pop.getPopulation().length; i++) {
            valor += pop.getPopulation()[i].getFitness();
            System.out.println("Value of Fitness: "+pop.getPopulation()[i].getFitness()+"%");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Total Fitness: "+valor+"%");

        System.out.println("\n-----------------------------------------------");


        //Prints each path ID/Cost/Fitness/City order(with coordinates)
         for (int i = 0; i < pop.getPopulation().length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Path ID: "+i+" | Cost: "+pop.getPopulation()[i].getCost()+" | Fitness: "+pop.getPopulation()[i].getFitness()+"%");
            System.out.print("Path is: ");
            for (int j = 0; j < pop.getPopulation()[i].getPath().length; j++) {
                System.out.print(pop.getPopulation()[i].getPath()[j].getId() +"("+pop.getPopulation()[i].getPath()[j].getX()+","+pop.getPopulation()[i].getPath()[j].getY()+")  ");

         }System.out.println("\n -----------------------------------------------------");
        }

        }



        else{//USING BRUTE FORTE METHOD

         FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);
         ArrayList<City> cities = new ArrayList<City>();

            for (int i = 0; i <file.getNumCities(); i++) {
            cities.add(file.getCities()[i]);
            }           

        ArrayList<City> best = new ArrayList<City>();
        Permutations permu = new Permutations();
        permu.permutations(cities);
            System.out.print("The shortest path is: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < permu.getBest().size(); i++) {
                System.out.print(permu.getBest().get(i).getId()+"("+permu.getBest().get(i).getX()+","+permu.getBest().get(i).getY()+")");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("It would Cost: "+permu.getCost());
        }

        long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - start; 
        System.out.println("Algorithm took: "+elapsedTime+" nano seconds to find a solution");
    }



    }
```

```
package ga;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Permutations {
    private int cost=999999;
    private ArrayList<City> best;



    public void permutations(ArrayList<City> list){
       permutations(null, list, null);
    }

    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(int cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public ArrayList<City> getBest() {
        return best;
    }

    public void setBest(ArrayList<City> best) {
        this.best = best;
    }

    public  ArrayList<City> permutations(ArrayList<City> prefix, ArrayList<City> suffix, ArrayList<ArrayList<City>> output){
       if(prefix == null)
          prefix = new ArrayList<City>();
       if(output == null)
          output = new ArrayList<ArrayList<City>>();
       if(suffix.size() == 1){
          ArrayList<City> newElement = new ArrayList<City>(prefix);
          newElement.addAll(suffix);
          int costNow=cost(newElement);
          if(costNow<this.cost){
              best=newElement;
              this.cost=costNow;
          }
          return best;
       }
       for(int i = 0; i < suffix.size(); i++){
          ArrayList<City> newPrefix = new ArrayList<City>(prefix);
          newPrefix.add(suffix.get(i));
          ArrayList<City> newSuffix = new ArrayList<City>(suffix);
          newSuffix.remove(i);
          permutations(newPrefix,newSuffix,output);
       }



       return best;
    }

    public  int cost(ArrayList<City> path){
       int cost=0;
        int i=0;
        while(i<path.size()-1){
           cost+=path.get(i).distance(path.get(i+1).getX(),path.get(i+1).getY());
            i++;
        }
        cost+=path.get(path.size()-1).distance(path.get(0).getX(), path.get(0).getY());
        return cost;
    }

}
```

```
package ga;

import java.util.Random;

public class Path implements Comparable {
    private City [] path;
    private int numCities;
    private int cost;
    private int fitness;

    public Path(int numCities) {
        this.numCities = numCities;
        CreatePath();
        cost =0;
        calculateCost();
        fitness =0;

    }
    public void calculateCost(){
        cost=0;
        int i=0;
        while(i<numCities-1){
           cost+=path[i].distance(path[i+1].getX(),path[i+1].getY());
            i++;
        }
        cost+=path[path.length-1].distance(path[0].getX(), path[0].getY());
    }

    public int getFitness() {
        return fitness;
    }

    public void setFitness(int fitness) {
        this.fitness = fitness;
    }
    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(int distance) {
        this.cost = distance;
    }
    /* Overload compareTo method */
    public int compareTo(Object obj){
     Path tmp = (Path) obj;
     if(this.cost < tmp.cost){
         return 1;
     }
     else if(this.cost > tmp.cost){
         return -1;
     }
     else{
         return 0;
     }
    }
     public void CreatePath(){
        path= new City[numCities];
        for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
            path[i]=new City(i,RandomNum(1, 99),RandomNum(1, 99));            
        }
    }

    public int RandomNum(int min, int max){
        return min+ (new Random()).nextInt(max-min);        
    }

    public City[] getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(City[] path) {
        this.path = path;
        calculateCost();
    }

    public int getNumCities() {
        return numCities;
    }

    public void setNumCities(int numCities) {
        this.numCities = numCities;
    }

}
```

```
package ga;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class FileReader {

    private int numCities;
    private double mutationRate;
    private City[] cities;
    private int curLine;
    private StringTokenizer st;
    private int arrayCount;
    private int x, y;
    private double crossoverRate;
    private String fileName;

    public FileReader(String fileName) {
        numCities = 0;
        mutationRate = 0;
        City[] cities = new City[0];
        curLine = 1;
        arrayCount = 0;        
        this.fileName=fileName;
        read();
    }

    public int getNumCities() {
        return numCities;
    }

    public void setNumCities(int numCities) {
        this.numCities = numCities;
    }

    public double getMutationRate() {
        return mutationRate;
    }

    public void setMutationRate(double mutationRate) {
        this.mutationRate = mutationRate;
    }

    public City[] getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

    public void setCities(City[] cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    public int getCurLine() {
        return curLine;
    }

    public void setCurLine(int curLine) {
        this.curLine = curLine;
    }

    public StringTokenizer getSt() {
        return st;
    }

    public void setSt(StringTokenizer st) {
        this.st = st;
    }

    public int getArrayCount() {
        return arrayCount;
    }

    public void setArrayCount(int arrayCount) {
        this.arrayCount = arrayCount;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void read() {

        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader("./"+fileName));
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (curLine == 1) {
                        st = new StringTokenizer(line, "=");
                        st.nextToken();
                        numCities = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                        cities = new City[numCities];
                    } else if (curLine == 2) {
                        st = new StringTokenizer(line, "=");
                        st.nextToken();
                        mutationRate = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                    }else if(curLine==3){
                        st = new StringTokenizer(line, "=");
                        st.nextToken();
                       crossoverRate = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                    }
                    else {
                        st = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");
                        st.nextToken();
                        String a = st.nextToken();
                        StringTokenizer stmp = new StringTokenizer(a, "=");
                        stmp.nextToken();
                        x = Integer.parseInt(stmp.nextToken());
                        String l = st.nextToken();
                        stmp = new StringTokenizer(l, "=");
                        stmp.nextToken();
                        y = Integer.parseInt(stmp.nextToken());

                        cities[arrayCount] = new City(arrayCount, x, y);
                        arrayCount++;
                    }
                    curLine++;

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!!");
        }
    }

    public double getCrossoverRate() {
        return crossoverRate;
    }

    public void setCrossoverRate(double crossoverRate) {
        this.crossoverRate = crossoverRate;
    }
}
```

```
package ga;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class Population {

    private int populationSize;
    private int numCities;
    private Path[] population;
    private double crossoverRate;
    private City[] child1;
    private City[] child2;
    private double mutationRate;
    private Path[] nextGen;
    private int done;

    public Population(int populationSize, int numCities, double crossoverRage, double mutationRate) {
        this.populationSize = populationSize;
        this.numCities = numCities;
        population = new Path[populationSize];
        this.crossoverRate = crossoverRage;
        this.mutationRate = mutationRate;
        this.nextGen = new Path[populationSize];
        Path p = new Path(numCities);
        done = 0;
        CreatePopulation(p);

    }

    public Population(int populationSize, int numCities, Path path, double crossoverRage, double mutationRate) {
        this.populationSize = populationSize;
        this.numCities = numCities;
        this.crossoverRate = crossoverRage;
        population = new Path[populationSize];
        this.mutationRate = mutationRate;
        this.nextGen = new Path[populationSize];
        done = 0;
        CreatePopulation(path);

    }

    public void CreatePopulation(Path p) {
        int i = 0;

        while (i < populationSize) {
            City[] tmpCity = new City[numCities];
            for (int j = 0; j < tmpCity.length; j++) {
                tmpCity[j] = p.getPath()[j];
            }
            Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(tmpCity));
            Path tmpPath = new Path(numCities);
            tmpPath.setPath(tmpCity);
            population[i] = tmpPath;
            i++;
        }
    }

    public int SelectParent() {
        int total = 0;
        //Selecting parents
        int totalCost = calculateTotalFitness();

        int fit = RandomNum(0, totalCost);
        int value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < population.length; i++) {
            value += population[i].getFitness();
            if (fit <= value) {
                return i;
            }//if(fit<=value){
        }
        return -1;

    }

    public boolean Mate() {
        //Generate a random number to check if the parents cross
        int check = RandomNum(0, 100);
        int parent1 = SelectParent();
        int parent2 = SelectParent();
        while (parent1 == parent2) {
            parent2 = SelectParent();
        }

        //check if there is going to be a crossover
        if (check <= (crossoverRate * 100)) {

            int crossoverPoint = RandomNum(0, population[parent1].getPath().length - 1);
            child1 = new City[numCities];
            child2 = new City[numCities];

            //crossing over
            for (int i = 0; i < crossoverPoint; i++) {
                child1[i] = population[parent2].getPath()[i];
                child2[i] = population[parent1].getPath()[i];
            }
            for (int i = crossoverPoint; i < numCities; i++) {
                child1[i] = population[parent1].getPath()[i];
                child2[i] = population[parent2].getPath()[i];
            }


            //Rearrange childs considering city repetition
            int cityChild1;
            int cityChild2;
            ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (int i = 0; i < crossoverPoint; i++) {
                cityChild1 = child1[i].getId();
                cityChild2 = child2[i].getId();

                //Get the positions of repeated values
                for (int j = crossoverPoint; j < numCities; j++) {
                    if (cityChild1 == child1[j].getId()) {
                        list1.add(j);
                    }
                    if (cityChild2 == child2[j].getId()) {
                        list2.add(j);
                    }
                }
            }

            //Find the missing values
            for (int i = 0; i < numCities; i++) {
                boolean found = false;
                //Fixing Child1
                for (int j = 0; j < numCities; j++) {
                    if (population[parent2].getPath()[i] == child1[j]) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (found == false) {
                    child1[list1.remove(list1.size() - 1)] = population[parent2].getPath()[i];
                }
                found = false;
                //Fixing Child2
                for (int j = 0; j < numCities; j++) {
                    if (population[parent1].getPath()[i] == child2[j]) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (found == false) {
                    child2[list2.remove(list2.size() - 1)] = population[parent1].getPath()[i];
                }
            }

//                     System.out.print("Parent 1: ");
//            for (int i = 0; i < numCities; i++) {
//                if (i == crossoverPoint) {
//                    System.out.print("| ");
//                }
//                System.out.print(population[parent1].getPath()[i].getId() + " ");
//            }
//            System.out.print("\nParent 2: ");
//            for (int i = 0; i < numCities; i++) {
//                if (i == crossoverPoint) {
//                    System.out.print("| ");
//                }
//                System.out.print(population[parent2].getPath()[i].getId() + " ");
//            }
//            System.out.print("\nChild 1: ");
//            for (int i = 0; i < numCities; i++) {
//                if (i == crossoverPoint) {
//                    System.out.print("| ");
//                }
//                System.out.print(child1[i].getId() + " ");
//            }
//            System.out.print("\nChild 2: ");
//            for (int i = 0; i < numCities; i++) {
//                if (i == crossoverPoint) {
//                    System.out.print("| ");
//                }
//                System.out.print(child2[i].getId() + " ");
//            }
//            System.out.println("");
//
//            //Repeated Values
//            for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
//                System.out.print(list1.get(i) + " ");
//            }
//            System.out.println("");
//            for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
//                System.out.print(list2.get(i) + " ");
//            }


            if (AddToGenerationCheckFull(child1, child2) == false) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }


        } else {

            if (AddToGenerationCheckFull(population[parent1].getPath(), population[parent1].getPath()) == false) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    public int getDone() {
        return done;
    }

    public void setDone(int done) {
        this.done = done;
    }

    public boolean AddToGenerationCheckFull(City[] child1, City[] child2) {
        if (done == populationSize) {
            return true;
        }
        Path newGenChild1 = new Path(numCities);
        Path newGenChild2 = new Path(numCities);
        newGenChild1.setPath(child1);
        newGenChild2.setPath(child2);
        if (done < populationSize - 2) {
            this.nextGen[done] = newGenChild1;
            this.nextGen[done + 1] = newGenChild2;
            this.done += 2;
            return false;
        } else if (done == populationSize - 2) {
            this.nextGen[done] = newGenChild1;
            this.nextGen[done + 1] = newGenChild2;
            done += 2;
            return true;
        } else {
            this.nextGen[done] = newGenChild1;
            done += 1;
            return true;
        }

    }

    public Path[] getNextGen() {
        return nextGen;
    }

    public void setNextGen(Path[] nextGen) {
        this.nextGen = nextGen;
    }

    public City[] Mutation(City[] child) {
        int check = RandomNum(0, 100);

        //Checks if its going to mutate
        if (check <= (mutationRate * 100)) {

            //finds the 2 cities that "mutate"
            int point1 = RandomNum(0, numCities - 1);
            int point2 = RandomNum(0, numCities - 1);
            while (point2 == point1) {
                point2 = RandomNum(0, numCities - 1);
            }

            //Cities are switched as result of mutation
            City city1 = child[point1];
            City city2 = child[point2];
            child[point1] = city2;
            child[point2] = city1;

        }
        return child;
    }

    public int RandomNum(int min, int max) {
        return min + (new Random()).nextInt(max - min);
    }

    public void FitnessOrder() {
        Arrays.sort(population);
        // double cost = calculateTotalCost();
        for (int i = 0; i < population.length; i++) {
//            double total = cost - population[i].getCost();
//            double fitness = (total * 100) / cost; 
//            fitness = 100 - fitness;
//            population[i].setFitness(fitness);
            int lol = 100000 / (population[i].getCost() + 1);
            population[i].setFitness(lol);
            //       System.out.println("Total: "+total + " "+" Cost: "+cost+" "+" Fitness: "+fitness+"%" );
        }

    }

    public int calculateTotalFitness() {
        int cost = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < population.length; i++) {
            cost += population[i].getFitness();
        }
        return cost;
    }

    public double getCrossoverRate() {
        return crossoverRate;
    }

    public void setCrossoverRate(double crossoverRage) {
        this.crossoverRate = crossoverRage;
    }

    public Path[] getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public void setPopulation(Path[] population) {
        this.population = population;
    }

    public int getPopulationSize() {
        return populationSize;
    }

    public void setPopulationSize(int populationSize) {
        this.populationSize = populationSize;
    }

    public int getNumCities() {
        return numCities;
    }

    public void setNumCities(int numCities) {
        this.numCities = numCities;
    }
}
```

```
package ga;

public class City {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int id;

    public City(int id,int x, int y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.id=id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int distance(int xOther,int yOther){
        return (int) Math.sqrt(((this.x-xOther)*(this.x-xOther))+((this.y-yOther)*(this.y-yOther)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's really helpful for me.